# How to see Word .doc variables

Tags: variables, layout, ms-word, ms-office, office-2003

Is there any possibility to see doc variables? It's Microsoft Word 2003, I have added a doc variable in a document, but if I take a look at the document I can't see there any variables. Is it possible to turn document variables visible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I solved it myself. To change fields visible mode you should use `ALT+F9`

Comment: _Document Variables_ are not fields and do no become visible with Alt + F9. You may be referring to a _Document Properties_ field instead.